# Auto clicking a dynamically added element on a site (using Greasemonkey)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I'm in the process of writing my first (small) greasemonkey script, but the target (website) ain't the easiest to start with.

My ISP's TV site is generating (unnecessary) choosing options on the fly when selecting a TV channel, here's how it goes.

When I select a channel the following contents is generated dynamically, and I would like to auto-click the option containing "This website" as soon as the code below appears :

```
<ul class="dropdown-wrapper" data-type="swipe_button_dropdown">
                <li>
                    <div class="dropdown-title" ng-bind-html="wb.title">Watch Live on</div>
                </li>
                <!----><li ng-repeat="item in wb.list" class="" style="">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" ng-class="{disabled: item.disabled}" ng-click="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; wb.send(item)" ng-bind-html="item.name">This website</a>
                </li><!----><li ng-repeat="item in wb.list" class="">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" ng-class="{disabled: item.disabled}" ng-click="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; wb.send(item)" ng-bind-html="item.name">Digicorder 68:61:50:63:BB:4F</a>
                </li><!----><li ng-repeat="item in wb.list" class="">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" ng-class="{disabled: item.disabled}" ng-click="!item.disabled &amp;&amp; wb.send(item)" ng-bind-html="item.name">Digibox 68:61:50:29:ED:9A</a>
                </li><!---->
            </ul>
```

Please, this is way above my hat to start, especially with the code being generated dynamically.
Anyone willing to help me on the right track ? Thank's a lot.

Comment: By "changes dynamically", is there a specific event (like a click or a timer) that causes that to appear that you can also listen to? Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: Hi Artyer, I've tried a couple of things already, I got rid of them since I kept failing, I specifically have trouble how to target that specific element, also, I have trouble with the element not being created on load but dynamically. There are a couple of events on which it can appear including after a click on the element like below ... (in next message, reply was too long)

Comment: `<a class="btn-action action-button" ng-class="{'btn--loading': wb.isLoading}" ng-click="wb.send(undefined, $event)" client-event="WATCH_BUTTON_CLICKED">
            <span clamp="1" clamp-value="Nu kijken" ng-bind="wb.label" class="clamping single-line"><span>Nu kijken</span></span>
            <div class="btn-spinner-container">
                <div class="btn-spinner btn-spinner--white"></div>
            </div>
        </a>`

Comment: Your question isn't very useful for the world yet, since there is no reproducible code triggering some content. You might want to investigate the `MutationObserver`. Is there some public requestable site?

Comment: Well, all of this is hidden behind a login and most probably an IP restricted access, since I don't expect a telecom provider giving access to non-members. Since this is way above my hat to start i think I better forget about it and move on. Thanks Artyer & Quasimodo's clone for willing to give a helping hand.